# Can I force a program to load a weakly-named assembly when it's linked to a strongly-named assembly?

Tags: .net, clr

I have a program that references a strongly named assembly which is in the gac.  I have a debug build of this assembly which I want to debug into, but it isn't strongly named.  Can I use a policy file or something to force the program to use the weakly named assembly?  Or do I have to recompile the program to reference the weakly named assembly?  (These assembles are purchased from a 3rd-party.  I have the source to them but I don't have the company's private key to strongly name my own build of them with the same key.)

Thanks,
Phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just changing the [AssemblyVersion] of the debug version would be the quick fix.  Running gacutil.exe to temporarily remove the assembly from the GAC would be another.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the assemblies to the Verification skip list by running `sn -Vr` in the Visual Studio Command Prompt.

This will tell the runtime not to verify the assemblies' signatures.
For security reasons, you should remove them when you finish.

Comment: No, it isn't being verified anyway in full trust.  The issue is to not let the CLR find the assembly, the GAC is always searched first.